# Sending the pointer of each row of a matrix to a function

Tags: c, arrays

I am learning memory allocation in C. I want to create a matrix of [10][20] using `malloc` such that each row is sent to a function to be processed. Is it enough to send only the pointer of each row? i.e. `*arr[0]`;

The following is a chunk of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **arr; // Buffer

int sumElements(int *arr[]){
 // do something
}


void main(){
    int i,j;
    arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int *)); // Allocate # of rows for the matrix

        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            arr[j]= malloc(20 * sizeof(int)); // Allocate # of entries in each row
            sumElements(*arr[j]); // send the current row to be processed by function
        }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The current row is not `*arr[j]`, but `arr[j]`.  The former is of type `int` while the latter is of type `int *`.  So `sumElements` should be passed a `int []` or `int *`, not a `int *[]`.

So the function definition should be:

```
int sumElements(int arr[])
```

And you should call it like this:

```
sumElements(arr[j]);
```

Comment: Oh! that makes sense.  THANK YOU

Comment: Does sumElements(arr[j]) process the entire 20 columns ?

Comment: @LM Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @LM The function will receive an array which is the row in question, so it can process each of the 20 columns.  If the function doesn't know how many columns there are, you should pass that as a parameter as well.

Comment: Great! Appreciate your immediate support.